# Can't start external service

Tags: android, service

I have an IntentService in app A that I am trying to start from app B.  When run I get

```
ActivityManager: Unable to start service Intent { cmp=com.xyz/.service.MyIntentService } U=0: not found
```

This is my IntentService code in app A

```
package com.xyz.service;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class MyIntentService extends IntentService {
    public MyIntentService() {
        super("MyIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.i("MyIntentService", "Intent Started");
    }
}
```

In app B's MainActivity I have the following

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.xyz", "com.xyz.service.MyIntentService"));
startService(i);
```

I've also declared the service in app A's AndroidManifest.xml

```
<service android:name=".service.MyIntentService" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true"></service>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: whats the output of `adb shell dumpsys package com.xyz` command? you could also try: `adb shell pm dump com.xyz` and the output is much more verbose - so first try `adb shell dumpsys ...`

Comment: Thanks!!  Turns out I had a typo in my package name.  Probably wouldn't have caught it without this command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in file A's AndroidManifest.xml, try this:

```
<service
           android:enabled="true"
           android:exported="true"
           android:name=".service.MyIntentService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.xyz.START_SERVICE" />
        </intent-filter>
</service>
```

and to start it from B:

```
Intent intent=new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.xyz", "com.xyz.service.MyIntentService"));
intent.addAction("com.xyz.START_SERVICE")
startService(intent);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work.  An IllegalArgumentException is thrown saying the Service Intent must be explicit.  After adding intent.setPackage("com.xyz") the original ActivityManager error occurs.

Comment: Thank you it worked.  Turns out I also had a typo in my package manifest.

Comment: Great! Feel free to mark it as the answer if it helped :)

Answer (score 2):

you should declare  permission in your A AndroidManifest.xml

```
<permission android:name="com.xyz.permission.PERMISSION_NAME"
            android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.xyz.permission.PERMISSION_NAME"/>

<service android:name=".service.MyIntentService"
             android:enabled="true"
             android:exported="true"
             android:permission="com.xyz.permission.PERMISSION_NAME"/>
```

and add user permission in your B AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.xyz.permission.PERMISSION_NAME"/>
```